# Is it possible to show my custom dialog when my form is dirty and user try to refresh page? Angular 15

Tags: angular

When a user dirty the form and wants to reload the page (F5, or a browser `Reload this page` button), i need to show them a confirmation window and handle their response: if yes, i execute the Http request, if no, i do some other logic.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  onBeforeUnload(event: BeforeUnloadEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = ''; 
  }
```

This approach doesn't work for me, it shows the confirmation window and executes the code I write here, but I need to execute the code depending on the user response, which I can't get here.

```
{ CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router'
```

Doesn't work for me either as it handles the routing change, it doesn't work when the page is refreshed.

UPD: `const choise = confirm()` inside `onBeforeUnload` does not work for me either, as it is blocked by the browser and does not work

Answer (score 0):

yes
you can use Mat dialog

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ModalConfirmComponent } from '../components/modals/modal-confirm/modal-confirm.component';

export interface HasUnsaveChanges {
  hasUnsaveChanges(): boolean;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FormWithSaveGuard implements CanDeactivate<HasUnsaveChanges> {
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  canDeactivate(
    component: HasUnsaveChanges
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (component.hasUnsaveChanges()) {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalConfirmComponent);
  return new Observable<boolean>((observer) => {
    dialogRef.componentInstance.confirmed.subscribe(() => {
      observer.next(true);
      observer.complete();
    });

    dialogRef.componentInstance.canceled.subscribe(() => {
      observer.next(false);
      observer.complete();
    });
  });
}
return true;
```

}
}

and in your component form you should implement the interface HasUnsaveChanges, and return the `hasUnsaveChanges(): boolean { console.log('Dirty', this.form.dirty); return this.form.dirty; }`

Comment: Oh, thanks for wanting to help, but the code you provided will only work when the route is changed, F5 or 'Reload this page' will not